# Why does javac allow "new CLS().new InnerCLS()" compile?

Tags: java, javac

Consider the following snippet:

(I came across this syntax when inspecting some decompiled class files and this is a minimal representation)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.Inner o = new Main().new Inner() {};

        System.out.println("Bye from " + o.getClass());
    }

    class Inner {}
}
```

This compiles and runs fine (I tested a bunch of JDKs).

**Can someone please explain how come this compiles and what does this code represent?**

This code creates 3 classes:

```
1. Main - This creates the following code (I removed the irrelevant parts):   
    new Main$1
    dup
    new Main
    dup
    invokespecial Method Main <init> ()V
    dup
    invokevirtual Method java/lang/Object getClass ()Ljava/lang/Class;
    pop
    invokespecial Method Main$1 <init> (LMain;)V

Why is it calling getClass (the result is popped anyway)?

2. Main$Inner - This class looks like as would expect an inner class to look

3. Main$1 - This creates the following class (I removed the irrelevant parts):
    final class Main$1 extends Main$Inner 
    method <init> : (LMain;)V 
    aload_0
    aload_1
    dup
    invokevirtual Method java/lang/Object getClass ()Ljava/lang/Class;
    pop
    invokespecial Method Main$Inner <init> (LMain;)V
    return

Again, why is it calling getClass (the result is popped anyway)?
```

BTW, it can be nested even further like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = new Main().new Inner1().new Inner2().new Inner3() {};

        System.out.println("Bye from " + o.getClass());
    }

    class Inner1 {
        class Inner2 {
            class Inner3 {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why should it not compile? the inner class is a valid class

Comment: Are you asking about "new CLS().new InnerCLS()", as your title suggests, or about the `{}` after it?

Comment: @sepp2k I'm asking about the "new CLS().new InnerCLS()"

Comment: @LenaBru Since when is it valid to write "<object>.new <another object>"? It's not a member?

Comment: Actually, on second though it's kind of like a static member. So it can be accessed through an instance too. But then why does it call "getClass"?

Comment: Then why did you include the `{}` in your code if it's not relevant to your question? 'Since when is it valid to write "<object>.new <another object>"?' Since Java 1.1, which introduced inner classes.

Comment: @EliFinkel Non-static inner classes are very much not like static members. They can *only* be accessed through instances.

Comment: Thank you all. Now I know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how instance (non-static) inner classes work. You need an instance of the outer class to instantiate instance of the inner class. This is another example:

```
var outer = new Outer();
var inner = outer.new Outer.Inner();
```

See:

- [The Java™ Tutorials: Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: Do you know about the `getClass` seemingly unnecessary call?

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be because of the extra `{};` at the end of assignment expression which I believe creates anonymous class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#syntax-of-anonymous-classes

Comment: It happens without the `{}` too

Comment: I think I've figured it out. The `getClass()` call is to fail fast calls like `((Outer)null).new Inner()`, rather than letting them fail later in a much less obvious way (similar to implicit assembly generated null pointer checks).

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes must be instantiated with a `this` pointer to the outer class.

The syntax `outer.new Inner()` is one way to achieve that (the new instance of `Inner` will have the value of `outer` as the outer.this reference.

This is equivalent to having a non-static method in the Main class:

```
class Main {

    Inner makeInner() {
        /// "this." is implied here, but it is there.
        return new Inner();
    }
    class Inner {
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. Can you point me to some docs? Also, why is getClass being called?

Comment: `getClass` is called in the `System.out.println() line`. Is probably being called just to demonstrate that you have an instance of the Inner class, and that it's underlying name is `Main$Inner`.

Comment: Nope. As you can see, `getClass` is getting called inside `Main$1`'s constructor